# How to add a subscriber to a list with MailChimp API v3.0 from an HTML page via jquery .ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm new to both MailChimp and PHP, and I need some help getting my static registration page to work with MailChimp API v3.0.

The goal here is to implement the MailChimp api to a static HTML page that collects user signups. I've done some research and followed through some code examples on this site, however, due to lack of experience in Restful API and PHP, I couldn't get anything to work. The form seems to not react to any input at all and all I'm getting is an empty page with the msg "Cannot POST /action.php". Below are my codes:

HTML

```
 <section id="mailchimp">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="action.php" id="form" method="post">
      <p class="sub-lead">* indicates required.</p>
      <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="form_email" placeholder="Email Address *" required="required">
      <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="form_fname" placeholder="First Name *" required="required">
      <input type="text" name="SURNAME" id="form_surname" placeholder="Last Name *" required="required">
      <input type="text" name="TELEPHONE" id="form_phone" placeholder="Phone Number *" required="required">
      <select name="ROOM" id="room">
        <option value="" disabled selected>I am interested in...</option>
        <option value="One Bed">1 Bedroom</option>
        <option value="One Bed">2 Bedroom</option>
        <option value="One Bed">3 Bedroom</option>
      </select>
      <select name="COUNTRY" id="country" required="required">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Country *</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
        <option value="Aaland Islands">Aaland Islands</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
        <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
        <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
        <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
        <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
        <option value="Antigua And Barbuda">Antigua And Barbuda</option>
        <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
        <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
        <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
        <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
        <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
        <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
        <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
        <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
        <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
        <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
        <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
        <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
        <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
        <option value="Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba">Bonaire, Saint Eustatius and Saba</option>
        <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
        <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
        <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
        <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
        <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
        <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
        <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
        <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
        <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
        <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
        <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
        <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
        <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
        <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
        <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
        <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
        <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
        <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
        <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
        <option value="Cote D'Ivoire">Cote D'Ivoire</option>
        <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
        <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
        <option value="Curacao">Curacao</option>
        <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
        <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
        <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
        <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
        <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
        <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
        <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
        <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
        <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
        <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
        <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
        <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
        <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
        <option value="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
        <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
        <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
        <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
        <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
        <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
        <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
        <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
        <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
        <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
        <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
        <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
        <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
        <option value="Guam">Guam</option>
        <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
        <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
        <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
        <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
        <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
        <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
        <option value="Heard and Mc Donald Islands">Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
        <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
        <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
        <option value="India">India</option>
        <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
        <option value="Iran">Iran</option>
        <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
        <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
        <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
        <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
        <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
        <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
        <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="Jersey  (Channel Islands)">Jersey  (Channel Islands)</option>
        <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
        <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
        <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
        <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
        <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
        <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
        <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
        <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
        <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
        <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
        <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
        <option value="Libya">Libya</option>
        <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
        <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
        <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
        <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
        <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
        <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
        <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
        <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
        <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
        <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
        <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
        <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
        <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
        <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
        <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
        <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
        <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
        <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
        <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
        <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
        <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
        <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
        <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
        <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
        <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
        <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
        <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
        <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
        <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
        <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
        <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
        <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
        <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
        <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
        <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
        <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
        <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
        <option value="North Korea">North Korea</option>
        <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
        <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
        <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
        <option value="Palestine">Palestine</option>
        <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
        <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
        <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
        <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
        <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
        <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
        <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
        <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
        <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
        <option value="Republic of Kosovo">Republic of Kosovo</option>
        <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
        <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
        <option value="Russia">Russia</option>
        <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
        <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
        <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
        <option value="Saint Martin">Saint Martin</option>
        <option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
        <option value="Samoa (Independent)">Samoa (Independent)</option>
        <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
        <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
        <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
        <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
        <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
        <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
        <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
        <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
        <option value="Sint Maarten">Sint Maarten</option>
        <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
        <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
        <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
        <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
        <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
        <option value="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
        <option value="South Korea">South Korea</option>
        <option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
        <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
        <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
        <option value="St. Helena">St. Helena</option>
        <option value="St. Pierre and Miquelon">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
        <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
        <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
        <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
        <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
        <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
        <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
        <option value="Syria">Syria</option>
        <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
        <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
        <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
        <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
        <option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
        <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
        <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
        <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
        <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
        <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
        <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
        <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
        <option value="Turks &amp; Caicos Islands">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option>
        <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
        <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
        <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
        <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
        <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
        <option value="USA Minor Outlying Islands">USA Minor Outlying Islands</option>
        <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
        <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
        <option value="Vatican City State (Holy See)">Vatican City State (Holy See)</option>
        <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
        <option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands (British)">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
        <option value="Virgin Islands (U.S.)">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
        <option value="Wallis and Futuna Islands">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
        <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select>
      <input type="checkbox" id="opt-in" name="opt-in" value="opt-in" required="required">Yes, I'd like to receive future updates from this project.<br>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
      <div id="signup-result"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

action.PHP

```
<?php
  /*
   * Add a 'member' to a 'list' via mailchimp API v3.x
   * @ http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members
   *
   * ================
   * BACKGROUND
   * Typical use case is that this code would get run by an .ajax() jQuery call or possibly a form action
   * The live data you need will get transferred via the global $_POST variable
   * That data must be put into an array with keys that match the mailchimp endpoints, check the above link for those
   * You also need to include your API key and list ID for this to work.
   * You'll just have to go get those and type them in here, see README.md
   * ================
   */

  // Set API Key and list ID to add a subscriber
  $api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us16'; 
  $list_id = 'xxxxxxxxxx';

  /* ================
   * DESTINATION URL
   * Note: your API URL has a location subdomain at the front of the URL string
   * It can vary depending on where you are in the world
   * To determine yours, check the last 3 digits of your API key
   * ================
   */
  $url = 'https://us16.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/';

  /* ================
   * DATA SETUP
   * Encode data into a format that the add subscriber mailchimp end point is looking for
   * Must include 'email_address' and 'status'
   * Statuses: pending = they get an email; subscribed = they don't get an email
   * Custom fields go into the 'merge_fields' as another array
   * More here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members
   * ================
   */
  $pfb_data = array(
    'email_address' => $_POST['emailname'],
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
      'FNAME'       => $_POST['firstname'],
      'LNAME'       => $_POST['lastname'],
      'TELEPHONE'   => $_POST['phone'],
      'ROOM'        => $_POST['room'],
      'COUNTRY'     => $_POST['country'],
    ),
  );

  // Encode the data
  $encoded_pfb_data = json_encode($pfb_data);

  // Setup cURL sequence
  $ch = curl_init();

  /* ================
   * cURL OPTIONS
   * The tricky one here is the _USERPWD - this is how you transfer the API key over
   * _RETURNTRANSFER allows us to get the response into a variable which is nice
   * This example just POSTs, we don't edit/modify - just a simple add to a list
   * _POSTFIELDS does the heavy lifting
   * _SSL_VERIFYPEER should probably be set but I didn't do it here
   * ================
   */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_pfb_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $results = curl_exec($ch); // store response
  $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // get HTTP CODE
  $errors = curl_error($ch); // store errors

  curl_close($ch);

  // Returns info back to jQuery .ajax or just outputs onto the page

  $results = array(
    'results' => $result_info,
    'response' => $response,
    'errors' => $errors
  );

  // Sends data back to the page OR the ajax() in your JS
  echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

register.js

```
// Signup form submission
$('#submit').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get data from form and store it
  var pfbSignupEMAIL = $('#form_email').val();
  var pfbSignupFNAME = $('#form_fname').val();
  var pfbSignupLNAME = $('#form_surname').val();
  var pfbSignupTELEPHONE = $('#form_phone').val();
  var pfbSignupROOM = $('#room').val();
  var pfbSignupCOUNTRY = $('#country').val();


  // Create JSON variable of retreived data
  var pfbSignupData = {
    'firstname': pfbSignupFNAME,
    'lastname': pfbSignupLNAME,
    'email': pfbSignupEMAIL,
    'phone': pfbSignupTELEPHONE,
    'room': pfbSignupROOM,
    'country': pfbSignupCOUNTRY,
  };

  // Send data to PHP script via .ajax() of jQuery
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'MailChimp.php',
    data: pfbSignupData,
    success: function (results) {
      $('#form_email').hide();
      $('#form_fname').hide();
      $('#form_surname').hide();
      $('#form_phone').hide();
      $('#room').hide();
      $('#country').hide();
      $('#signup-result').text('Thanks for adding yourself to the email list. We will be in touch.');
      console.log(results);
    },
    error: function (results) {
      $('signup-result').html('<p>Sorry but we were unable to add you into the email list.</p>');
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't want to use action.php instead of MailChimp.php in your ajax call?

```
// Send data to PHP script via .ajax() of jQuery
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'action.php',
  data: pfbSignupData,
  success: function (results) {
    $('#form_email').hide();
    $('#form_fname').hide();
    $('#form_surname').hide();
    $('#form_phone').hide();
    $('#room').hide();
    $('#country').hide();
    $('#signup-result').text('Thanks for adding yourself to the email list. We will be in touch.');
    console.log(results);
  },
  error: function (results) {
    $('signup-result').html('<p>Sorry but we were unable to add you into the email list.</p>');
    console.log(results);
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: I tried that, both don't work :/  it returns "Cannot POST /action.php"